# Is Jihad Al-Nikah (جهاد النكاح) an Islamic rule?

Tags: sharia, nikah, islamic-basis, jihad

I heard about Jihad Al-Nikah in television and radio, especially in the Syrian war which Saudi cleric gave a fatwa about it. Does it exist in Islam?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing in Islam as Jihad un-nikah. I bring you the [history](http://www.mashreghnews.ir/fa/news/252656/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D9%86%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AD-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B9%D8%A7-%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF) of this story.

Firstly, this Fatwa was issued by a news network called Al-Jadid in Lebanon on December 2012. It had claimed that Saudi sheikh Al-Arifi has issued a Fatwa about Jahad-u-nikah and made it Halal. But After this news, Al-Arifi and his companions  rejected it.

Then in march 27, 2012, Pan-Arabist newspaper called Al-Hayat from Lebanon issued an article about Tunisian girls, who leave their countries to attend Jahadu-Nikah because of Mr. Al-Arifi's Fatwa. But the report provided no evidence that this Fatwa was issued officially by Al-Arifi or other Muftis.

The next propaganda was in July 2013. In that time, Some news network such as Al-Arabia and Associated press issued several article about jahadu-Nikah of Egypt Akhmatova-Muslimin women just on the basis of a Facebook post. And Russia today in those days Have a report from the women who got pregnant and left Syria.

Roth Michelson, Author and journalist who spent some time in Syria in September 2012, is one who has written extensively about the war in Syria and sexual abuses, however, he highly doubts this rumor is correct, and says that widespread dissemination of this story is owe several thoughts called racist and Orientalism as they are hidden in this.

Answer (score 1):

**There is nothing in Islam called Jihad An-Nikah (sex Jihad).**

It was propaganda made by some people and was widely spread by those who hate the Saudi cleric.

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0k9iMclPQqc) of him denying it and then stating that the tweet that he sent was photoshopped to make it look like he has issued Jihad An-Nikah fatwa.

Here is the [photoshopped image](http://elbashayer.com/upload/img/1364487978cz7xithfzp3.jpg) (**205** characters which Twitter doesn't allow)

Comment: I declare it in my answer